# How to convert this LINQ Query result back to DataTable object?

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have DataTable object (`OutputDT1`), I want to use LINQ to group by column `ConfirmedBy`, then convert it back to a `DataTable` object which has only two columns `ConfirmBy` and `Count`.

```
var result = from row in OutputDT1.AsEnumerable()
             group row by new
             {
                 ConfirmedBy = row.Field<string>("ConfirmedBy")
             } 
             into grp
             select new
             {
                 ConfirmedBy = grp.Key.ConfirmedBy,
                 Count = grp.Count(),
             };
```

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6ffcb247-77fb-40b4-bcba-08ba377ab9db/converting-a-list-to-datatable

Comment: So what is the problem???

Comment: I think you would need to build your own extension method for that one.

Comment: Why would you want to turn it back into a DataTable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
foreach(var item in result)
{
  dt.Rows.Add(item.ConfirmedBy, item.count);
}
```

Comment: I see, is there any built-in function of .NET that can do the job that I didn't know of?

Comment: There is one `CopyToDataTable` but that would not work for you since, you are selecting an anonymous object. You can't use that for your situation. I am not sure if there is any .Net framework built-in method for something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Using the solution from [How to: Implement CopyToDataTable<T> Where the Generic Type T Is Not a DataRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx)

we can write:

```
var result = (from row in OutputDT1.AsEnumerable()
                group row by row.Field<string>("ConfirmedBy") into grp
                select new
                {
                    ConfirmedBy = grp.Key,
                    Count = grp.Count(),
                }).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: @J-CSharper What's the error?  And did you include the implementation from the given link into your project?

Comment: I see, if I have to use this implementation, I rather use the method that provided by Habib. It's way simpler